# Export data to variables

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm trying export data to variables. I have data in this form:

```
{
  "data":[{
    "unread": 1,
    "id":"1111",
    "updated_time":"2015-01-21T00:00:38+0000",
    "comments":{
      "data":[{
        "id":"1111_2222",
        "from":
        {
          "id":"9999",
          "name":"John"
        },
        "message":"Hello Steve, how are you?",
        "created_time":"2015-01-21T00:00:38+0000"
      }]
    }
  }]
}
```

I have following code but it exports only unread, id and updated_time. However I need even data from comments (message, id, name - from).

```
foreach ($fb_response->data as $item) {
    echo 'unread: ' . $item->unread . '<br />';
    echo 'From ID: ' . $item->id . '<br />';
    echo 'Time: ' . $item->updated_time;
}
```

Comment: Where is data coming from?

Comment: It is decoded json string from facebook graph api explorer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3555356/4563843 this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another loop?

```
$comments = $item->comments->data;
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->id;
    echo $comment->from->id;
    echo $comment->from->name;
    echo $comment->message;
    echo $comment->created_time;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your last echo was not terminated properly. Try this:

```
foreach($fb_response->data as $item){
echo 'unread: ' . $item->unread . '<br />';
echo 'From ID: ' . $item->id . '<br />';
echo 'Time: ' . $item->updated_time ;
}
```

Comment: I don't think, that is the main problem. OP probably just does not know how to access the nested data, I would assume

Comment: Thank you for comment. I know, this is not a problem, I just don't know how to write to a variable message and name. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sirko described the main problem.