# how to get data from nested objects in json using php

Tags: php, json

Could you give me some advice how to get data from this file?

I need to receive, for example, a list of stops and lines, or other data from the most nested objects, but I don't now how to do that with nested objects in JSON.

```
{
    "stops": {
        "11": "Winna-Karpacka",
        "21": "Piwna",
        "31": "RondoTysiąclecia",
        "41": "Piątkowicka-Wiączyńska",
        "51": "Taczańska",
        "61": "Komarzewska",
        "12": "Winna-Działki",
        "22": "Piwna-Karpacka",
        "32": "RondoTysiąclecia",
        "42": "Piątkowicka",
        "52": "Taczańska",
        "62": "Komarzewska-Wiączyńska"
    },
    "lines": {
        "1": {
            "variants": {
                "16": [{
                    "11": 0
                }, {
                    "21": 3
                }, {
                    "31": 5
                }, {
                    "41": 10
                }, {
                    "51": 12
                }, {
                    "61": 16
                }],
                "61": [{
                    "62": 0
                }, {
                    "52": 3
                }, {
                    "42": 6
                }, {
                    "32": 8
                }, {
                    "22": 14
                }, {
                    "12": 16
                }]
            },
            "departures": {
                "16": [
                    "04:00",
                    "04:50",
                    "05:40",
                    "06:30",
                    "07:20",
                    "08:10",
                    "09:00",
                    "10:00",
                    "11:00",
                    "12:00",
                    "13:00",
                    "14:00",
                    "14:50",
                    "15:40",
                    "16:30",
                    "17:20",
                    "18:10",
                    "19:00",
                    "20:00",
                    "21:00",
                    "22:00"
                ],
                "61": [
                    "04:25",
                    "05:15",
                    "06:05",
                    "06:55",
                    "07:45",
                    "08:35",
                    "09:30",
                    "10:30",
                    "11:30",
                    "12:30",
                    "13:30",
                    "14:25",
                    "15:15",
                    "16:05",
                    "16:55",
                    "17:45",
                    "18:35",
                    "19:30",
                    "20:30",
                    "21:30"
                ]
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "variants": {
                "25": [{
                    "21": 0
                }, {
                    "31": 2
                }, {
                    "41": 7
                }, {
                    "51": 9
                }],
                "52": [{
                    "52": 0
                }, {
                    "42": 3
                }, {
                    "32": 5
                }, {
                    "22": 11
                }]
            },
            "departures": {
                "25": [
                    "10:15",
                    "10:45",
                    "11:15",
                    "11:45",
                    "12:15",
                    "12:45",
                    "13:15",
                    "13:45",
                    "14:15",
                    "14:45",
                    "15:15",
                    "15:45",
                    "16:15",
                    "16:45",
                    "17:15",
                    "17:45"

                ],
                "52": [
                    "10:30",
                    "11:00",
                    "11:30",
                    "12:00",
                    "12:30",
                    "13:00",
                    "13:30",
                    "14:00",
                    "14:30",
                    "15:00",
                    "15:30",
                    "16:00",
                    "16:30",
                    "17:00",
                    "17:30"
                ]
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "variants": {
                "35": [{
                    "31": 0
                }, {
                    "41": 12
                }, {
                    "51": 22
                }],
                "53": [{
                    "51": 0
                }, {
                    "41": 10
                }, {
                    "31": 22
                }]
            },
            "departures": {
                "34": [
                    "01:10",
                    "02:10",
                    "03:10"
                ],
                "43": [
                    "01:40",
                    "02:40",
                    "03:40"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
$str = file_get_contents('dane.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
echo $json['stops']['11'];
```

Comment: `json_decode($json_data)` study about it

Comment: have you some code you messed up with and that we can check ? you have some json data, many ways to work around ;)

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/3555356

Comment: i checked your solution with `$json['stops']['11']` and it worked for me. You can use the apropriate looping `foreach($data["stops"] as $key => $value)` to get the keys and values that you want.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode`, then use this function I wrote to generate the appropriate PHP code to access any specific element in your JSON.

```
function jsonGeneratePhp($json, $phpString = '$json') {
    if (is_array($json)) {
        echo "$phpString<br>";
        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            jsonGeneratePhp($value, "{$phpString}['$key']");
        }
    } elseif (is_object($json)) {
        echo "$phpString<br>";
        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                jsonGeneratePhp($value, "{$phpString}->{{$key}}");
            } else {
                jsonGeneratePhp($value, "{$phpString}->$key");
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "$phpString = $json<br>";
    }
}

$str = file_get_contents('dane.json');
$json = json_decode($str);
jsonGeneratePhp($json);
```

This will generate a bunch of PHP statements that correspond to each piece of your JSON data, like this:

```
$json
$json->stops
$json->stops->{11} = Winna-Karpacka
$json->stops->{21} = Piwna
...
```

- Anything that ends in an `= something` is a value.

  > for example: `echo $json->stops->{11}; // Winna-Karpacka`
- Anything that does *not* end in an `= something` is an array or an object that you can iterate with `foreach`.

  > for example: `foreach ($json->stops as $stopId => $stopName) { ... }`