# How to parse nested JSON sent via AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Say I have this AJAX sent via jQuery to a PHP server

```
$.ajax({
    url: woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes.ajax_url,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.success) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

and `data` looks like this

```
data = {
    order_id: woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes.post_id,
    order_items : [
        {
            order_item_id: 69420,
            amount: 420
        },
        {
            order_item_id: 42069,
            amount: 69
        }
    ]
};
```

What I have found out is by using PHP's `$_POST`, I can access the order id like this

```
$order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
```

However, I am not sure of how I can access stuff inside `order_items` from `data`. From what I've seen in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555335/php-decode-nested-json), there's a PHP function called `json_decode()`, but I'm not so sure of how to use this together with AJAX or `$_POST`.

Comment: Send data like JSON.stringify(data) in ajax and decode this in php using json_decode()

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986235/how-to-use-json-stringify-and-json-decode-properly/37625282#:~:text=When%20you%20save%20some%20data,following%20code%20worked%20for%20me.&text=from%20the%20question)-,%24data%20%3D%20json_decode(%24_POST%5B%22JSONfullInfoArray%22%5D)%3B,%24_POST%5B%22JSONfullInfoArray%22%5D)%3B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax()` doesn't use JSON encoding, it sends URL-encoded format, so there's no need to use `json_decode()`.

To access the nested data, just use ordinary array accessing in the `$_POST` variable.

```
foreach ($_POST['order_items'] as $item) {
    echo "Item ID: " . $item['order_item_id'] . "<br>";
    echo "Amount: " . $item['amount'] . "<br>";
}
```